# Is there a way to check who modified view in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I wanted to check if there is way to audit the "CREATE VIEW" to check who created/modified view, I found couple of query that shows owner of the view but not when or if modified by who.

help appreciate it.

regards

Comment: Check the logfiles

Comment: You can create a [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html). But for checking in hindsight, there's only the logs - postgres does not keep a "lastModifiedBy" field (similar to the owner), if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: this query that I found i.e will find the view and and who created with the ddl, but does not shows when this was created

select * from pg_catalog.pg_views
where schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
order by schemaname, viewname;

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have not enabled logfiles unfortunately